# Segmentation Fault 11 when compiling swift file with enum in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segmentation-fault

When trying to compile a Swift file such as this one (as part of a project), Xcode (Version **7.3.1**) throws a segmentation fault 11 `while emitting SIL for 'operationForOperationType'`

```
import Foundation

enum OperationType: String{
    case Addition = "∑"

    func operationForOperationType() -> ([Double], [[Double]]? -> Double){
        switch self {
            case OperationType.Addition:
                return {$0.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})}
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a compiler bug or actually the result of the given code? Other variations of the code (more than one case, switch on a given `OperationType` instead of `self`) also resulted in a segmentation fault 11.

**Edit:** Remove .output (a copy-paste-error)

**Edit II:** The function's purpose is to return a closure for a given `OperationType`. For example, if my `OperationType` is addition, I want it to return the closure that adds elements in the array. This, of course, is a simplification. It might occur, that I want a closure to be returned, which combines elements in the array and a two dimensional array (think matrix-vector multiplication with a later dot-product).

Usage may be, for example:

```
var op = OperationType.Addition
let f = op.operationForOperationType()
let arr: [Double] = [1, 5, 2]
f(arr, nil)
//-> 8
```

Comment: Doing nested closures is probably a bad idea, what does the `$0` and `$1` in your `combine` closure refer to? what is `output`?

Comment: A crashing compiler is always a bug and should be reported. – But it is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. The return type is specified as a tuple, and the return value is a closure. And why the optional nested array `[[Double]]?` ?– It compiles if you change the signature to `func operationForOperationType() -> ([Double] -> Double)`, is that what you meant?

Comment: @luk2302 As far as I understand, combine combines the "sum-element" with the next element in the array. $0 therefore refers to this "sum-element" (I unfortunately don't know the actual term for this) and $1 is the next element in the array. Please see my edit concerning output.

Comment: @MartinR I actually need the second parameter for the closure (for future additions). Is this not what [Double], [[Double]]? -> Double) expresses?

Comment: Perhaps it becomes more clear if you add an example how the function is to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: if the compiler is crashing you might want to submit a bug report to apple.

Secondly regarding your code: Took me a while to figure out what is wrong here! Your declared return type is **not** a closure!

```
func operationForOperationType() -> ([Double], [[Double]]? -> Double) {
```

This line means the function returns a tuple of one `[Double]` and one closure of type `[[Double]]? -> Double`. It does **not** return a closure whose inputs are `[Double]` and `[[Double]]?` and returns a `Double`.

To correct the return type to actually specify to return *just* a closure you have to write:

```
func operationForOperationType() -> ([Double], [[Double]]?) -> Double {
```

Note the moved closing `)`!

Now we can get to the actual implementation of the return value:

```
func operationForOperationType() -> ([Double], [[Double]]?) -> Double {
    switch self {
    case OperationType.Addition:
        return { (a, b) in a.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})}
    }
}
```

Since we defined the input to be of type `([Double], [[Double]]?)`, a tuple, we have to either access those parameters via `$0.0` and `$0.1` or we write `(a, b) in` to map the first tuple value to `a` and the second to `b`.

Now everything compiles. I still do not know what you want to do with `b`, but that is none on my business ;)

Putting it all together:

```
enum OperationType: String{
    case Addition = "∑"

    func operationForOperationType() -> ([Double], [[Double]]?) -> Double {
        switch self {
        case OperationType.Addition:
            return { (a, b) in a.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})}
        }
    }
}

var op = OperationType.Addition
let f = op.operationForOperationType()
let arr: [Double] = [1, 5, 2]
f(arr, nil) // actually outputs 8 now
```